# Reading a CSV from GitHub using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, github, python-requests

I am trying to access a specific CSV from GitHub

https://github.com/tdwg/rs.tdwg.org/blob/master/terms/terms.csv

To pull this CSV into Python, I can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tdwg/rs.tdwg.org/master/terms/terms.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

However, this often (but not always) runs for a long time - without error - then I abort the script. The CSV is not very large, the data are retrieved in under a second when it runs as desired.

I have also tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tdwg/rs.tdwg.org/master/terms/terms.csv'

response = requests.get(url)
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.content.decode('utf-8')))
```

In this case, the line `response = requests.get(url)` is what is taking all the time.

I cannot figure out why this is taking so long, nor why this doesn't happen all of the time.

Some relevant points:

- My internet connection is fine
- I do not want to pull the repo or download the CSV to my local machine. I am building a tool that needs to always retrieve the latest version of this file.
- Pandas version 1.5.2
- Python version 3.8.10

Comment: How frequently do you query the file? Your might just be rate-limited by github's servers

Comment: @mozway I am accessing the file dozens of times a day. However, I encounter the problem on my first try of the day.

Comment: This has no particular reason to happen. I tried to get the file 200 times in a loop and the mean access is 0.13s.

Comment: @Corralien and yet it happens. Could be an issue with my setup?

Comment: Your setup is perfectly fine. In fact, there is no limitation. GitHub uses varnish cache servers to speed up content delivery!

Comment: @Corralien so what is the problem?

Comment: Honestly... I don't know. Try your code on another machine. You can also try Colab. As you use HTTPS, check the time of your computer.

Comment: Maybe a DNS issue? what if you try to query the DNS for `raw.githubusercontent.com` before starting your script?

Comment: @mozway

`import dns.resolver

# Set the DNS server to query
resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
resolver.nameservers = ['8.8.8.8']  # Google's public DNS server

# Query a domain name
result = resolver.query('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tdwg/rs.tdwg.org/master/terms/terms.csv')

# Print the IP addresses associated with the domain name
for ip in result:
    print(ip)`

I get this:

`NXDOMAIN: None of DNS query names exist: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tdwg/rs.tdwg.org/master/terms/terms.csv.,`

Comment: You need to query the domain only, not an URL

Comment: @mozway seems fine once I query `raw.githubusercontent.com`, it prints 4 different IPs